# How to build relations between classes using c#?

Tags: c#, class

I am working on a project that will allow me to build reports dynamically. So far I am able to build reports dynamically using direct relation between 2 classes  only. 
But, in order for me to be able to make the application more robust, I want to be able to find a relation between classes recursivly or via chain of relations. I will explain this more below

I have the following base class

```
public abstract class ReportTemplate
{
    public abstract List<IReportColumn> ReportColumns { get; }
    public abstract List<IReportRelationMapping> ReportRelationsMappings { get; }
    protected abstract IReportDataSource ReportDataSource { get; }
    private readonly IQueryExecutor queryExecutor;
    private readonly IQueryBuilder queryBuilder;

    protected ReportTemplate(IQueryBuilder queryBuilder, IQueryExecutor queryExecutor)
    {
        this.queryExecutor = queryExecutor;
        this.queryBuilder = queryBuilder;
    }

    public IReportModel CreateReport()
    {
        var model = new ReportModel(this.queryBuilder, this.queryExecutor);
        model.SetDataSource(ReportDataSource);
        foreach (var ReportRelationsMapping in this.ReportRelationsMappings)
        {
            model.AddReportRelationMapping(ReportRelationsMapping);
        }

        foreach (var repotColumn in this.ReportColumns)
        {
            model.AddReportColumn(repotColumn);
        }

        return model;
    }

}
```

Then I have multiple classes that extends this base class. Here are some example of classes that extend my base class `ReportTemplate`

```
public class CustomerTemplate : ReportTemplate
{
    private readonly IQueryExtractor QueryExtractor;
    private readonly TableMapper<Customer> customerMapper;
    private readonly TableMapper<Client> clientMapper;
    private readonly TableMapper<CustomerToTeam> customerToTeamMapper;
    private readonly TableMapper<Team> teamMapper;

    public CustomerTemplate(DbContext context)
        : base(new QueryBuilder(), new QueryExecutor(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        this.QueryExtractor = new QueryExtractor(context);
        this.customerMapper = new TableMapper<Customer>(QueryExtractor, "Customer");
        this.clientMapper = new TableMapper<Client>(QueryExtractor, "CustomerTemplate_Client");
        this.customerToTeamMapper = new TableMapper<CustomerToTeam>(QueryExtractor, "CustomerTemplate_CustomerToTeam");
    }

    public override List<IReportColumn> ReportColumns
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<IReportColumn>
            {
                customerMapper.Column("Customer Id", x=> x.Id),
                customerMapper.Column("First Name", x => x.FirstName),
                customerMapper.Column("Last Name", x => x.LastName),
                customerMapper.Column("Phone", x => x.Phone),
                customerMapper.Column("E-Mail Adress", x => x.Email),
                customerMapper.Column("Client Id", x => x.ClientId),
                customerMapper.Column("Current Team Id", x => x.CurrentTeamId),

            };
        }
    }
    //This should contain direct relations only
    public override List<IReportRelationMapping> ReportRelationsMappings
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<IReportRelationMapping>
            { 
                //Relation to Client
                new ReportRelationMapping
                {
                    LocalRelation = this.customerMapper.GetForeignRelation(x => x.ClientId),
                    ForeignRelation = this.clientMapper.GetForeignRelation(x => x.Id),
                },

                //Relation to CustomerToClients
                new ReportRelationMapping
                {
                    LocalRelation = this.customerMapper.GetForeignRelation(x => x.Id),
                    ForeignRelation = this.customerToTeamMapper.GetForeignRelation(x => x.CustomerId),
                },

            };

        }
    }

    protected override IReportDataSource ReportDataSource
    {
        get 
        {
            return customerMapper.GetReportDataSource(); 
        }
    }

}
```

And here is another one i.e. `CustomerToTeamTemplate`

```
public class CustomerToTeamTemplate : ReportTemplate
{
    private readonly IQueryExtractor QueryExtractor;
    private readonly TableMapper<CustomerToTeam> customerToTeamMapper;
    private TableMapper<Customer> customerMapper;
    private TableMapper<Team> teamMapper;

    public CustomerToTeamTemplate(DbContext context)
        : base(new QueryBuilder(), new QueryExecutor(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        this.QueryExtractor = new QueryExtractor(context);
        this.customerToTeamMapper = new TableMapper<CustomerToTeam>(QueryExtractor, "CustomerToTeam");
        var customerMapper = new TableMapper<Customer>(QueryExtractor, "CustomerToTeam_Customer");
        var teamMapper = new TableMapper<Team>(QueryExtractor, "CustomerToTeam_Team");
    }

    public override List<IReportColumn> ReportColumns
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<IReportColumn>
            {
                customerToTeamMapper.Column("Customer To Team Relation Id", x=> x.Id),
                customerToTeamMapper.Column("Related Customer Id", x => x.CustomerId),
                customerToTeamMapper.Column("Related Team Id", x => x.TeamId),                    
            };
        }
    }

    public override List<IReportRelationMapping> ReportRelationsMappings
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<IReportRelationMapping>
            { 
                //Relation to Team
                new ReportRelationMapping
                {
                    LocalRelation = customerToTeamMapper.GetForeignRelation(x => x.TeamId),
                    ForeignRelation = teamMapper.GetForeignRelation(x => x.Id),
                },

                //Relation to Customer
                new ReportRelationMapping
                {
                    LocalRelation = customerToTeamMapper.GetForeignRelation(x => x.CustomerId),
                    ForeignRelation = customerMapper.GetForeignRelation(x => x.Id),
                },

            };
        }
    }

    protected override IReportDataSource ReportDataSource
    {
        get 
        {
            return customerToTeamMapper.GetReportDataSource(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Here is one more class

```
public class TeamTemplate : ReportTemplate
{
    private readonly IQueryExtractor QueryExtractor;
    private readonly TableMapper<Team> teamMapper;

    public TeamTemplate(DbContext context)
        : base(new QueryBuilder(), new QueryExecutor(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        QueryExtractor = new QueryExtractor(context);
        teamMapper = new TableMapper<Team>(QueryExtractor, "Team");
    }

    public override List<IReportColumn> ReportColumns
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<IReportColumn>
            {
                teamMapper.Column("Team Id", x => x.Id),
                teamMapper.Column("Team Name", x => x.Name)
            };
        }
    }

    //There are no direct relations here!
    public override List<IReportRelationMapping> ReportRelationsMappings
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<IReportRelationMapping>();
        }
    }

    protected override IReportDataSource ReportDataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return teamMapper.GetReportDataSource();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the method `public override List<IReportRelationMapping> ReportRelationsMappings` in each derived class will define the direct relation between current class and other classes.

For example, in my class `CustomerToTeamTemplate` the first relation will establish a direct relation between the `CustomerToTeamTemplate` class and the `TeamTemplate` class. The same class will also contain another relation to the `CustomerClass`. Since `CustomerToTeamTemplate` has direct relation, I can search the relationMappings list and figure out all the relations or all the routes I can take. 
So the relations/direction that I can take will be one of the following

```
CustomerToTeamTemplate > CustomerTemplate
CustomerToTeamTemplate > TeamTemplate
```

Now if you look at the `CustomerClass` class you will see a relation between `CustomerTemplate` and `CustomerToTeamTemplate`. Which will look like this

```
CustomerTemplate > CustomerToTeamTemplate
```

But since `CustomerToTeamTemplate` has the following relation `CustomerToTeamTemplate > TeamTemplate` then I should be able to recorsivly figure out that there is an indirect relation between `CustomerTemplate` and `TeamTemplate` via the `CustomerToTeamTemplate` class.

```
CustomerTemplate > CustomerToTeamTemplate > TeamTemplate
```

One way I think I can do such a relation is by passing the relation of the foreign class when creating the relation something like this in the `CustomerTemplate` class I will change the relation to something like this

```
CustomerToTeamTemplate customerToTeamTemplate = new CustomerToTeamTemplate(this.Context);

//Relation to CustomerToClients
new ReportRelationMapping
{
    LocalRelation = this.customerMapper.GetForeignRelation(x => x.Id, this.ReportRelationsMappings),
    ForeignRelation = this.customerToTeamMapper.GetForeignRelation(x => x.CustomerId, customerToTeamTemplate.ReportRelationsMappings),
},

But this isn't working for me because I am creating an infinate loop when passing this.ReportRelationsMappings to it self.
```

Is there a better way to do this?

How can I establish such a relation between my classes?

Comment: I am wonder, why would I get 2 votes to close this question with 0 comment?

Comment: Because it is too broad? And is all that code really needed to explain what is wrong? Assuming it is a code issue, not a design problem.